# Nambu-Goto induced metric

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, metric-tensor, action

I'm having a bit of a confusion about deriving the components of the induced metric related to the Nambu-Goto action:

The induced metric is defined as:

$$g_{ab} = \eta_{uv} \frac{\partial X^{u}}{\partial x^a} \frac{\partial X^{v}}{\partial x^b}$$

where $\eta_{uv}$ is the Minkowskian metric. Wikipedia article and my textbook says that the $g_{t \sigma}$ component is given by: $$\dot{X} \cdot X',$$ but, I am not seeing how, I get:

$$g_{t \sigma} = \eta_{uv} \dot{X}^{u} X'^{v}.$$    How does this become $\dot{X} X'$, since $\eta_{uv}$ is diagonal, so shouldn't all the cross-terms of the induced metric be $0$?

Comment: $\eta_{\mu\nu}\dot{X}^\mu X'^\nu=\dot{X}\cdot X'$; presumably the $\dot{X}X'$ you see is meant to be $\dot{X}\cdot X'$

Comment: Oh! It's a scalar product! I see. I downloaded my book on Kindle, and the dot was missing, no joke. Thanks!

Comment: But, just out of curiosity: if $\eta_{uv}$ is indeed diagonal, then, Einstein summation says: $g_{t \sigma} = \eta_{00} \dot{X}^{0} X'^{0} + \eta_{01} \dot{X}^{0} X'^{1} + ...$ and so on, doesn't the first term go to zero because $X'^{0} = 0$, and the second term go to zero because $\eta_{01} = 0$, i.e, Minkowski is diagonal? So, shouldn't all cross-terms like this go to zero for similar reasons? Thanks.

Comment: Then $g_{t\sigma}=-\dot{X}^0X'^0+\dot{X}^1X'^1+\ldots+\dot{X}^nX'^n$, where $n$ is the number of spatial dimensions on your Minkowski space.